# HTML and or CSS to automatically produce simple search filter images / options

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to display a list of search filters on an HTML page for many permutations of a product's configuration

there are a number of tray slot options:

- 4 tray slots
- 5 tray slots
- 6 tray slots
- 7 tray slots
- 8 tray slots
- 9 tray slots
- 10 tray slots
- 11 tray slots

and for each tray slot option there are a number of configurations available... a basket takes up 2 tray slots, and a tray takes one tray slot, so for the 6 tray option the permutations are:

- 2 baskets, 2 trays
- 1 basket, 4 trays
- 0 baskets, 6 trays
- 3 baskets, 0 trays

i need images for each combination to make the search filters easier to understand by the user...

e.g for the 11 tray option, the search filter image would look something like:

[image]

and for one of the 11 tray slot combinations, the 9 tray and 1 basket option would look like:

[image: 9 trays 1 basket]

Can I use css or some dynamic image / icon creator to automatically create the image / css display feature to create these permutations dynamically? Otherwise maintaining and creating these images could be tiresome

Comment: Why not try something, then come back if you face a problem?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it. Use 3 images and create a case for each img.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone with this for the moment. Any comments welcome on how to improve the css / html

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
     .trapezoid {
     border-bottom: 1.2vw solid grey;
     border-left: 0.8vw solid transparent;
     border-right: 0.8vw solid transparent;
     height: 0;
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     margin: 0.5vw;
     }
     .rectangle {
     height: 0.4vw;
     background-color: grey;
     margin:0.2vw;
     }
     .option-wrapper {
     float: left;
     margin: 0.5vw;
     width: 5.0vw;
     border: 0.1vw solid grey;
     }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span class="option-wrapper">
   <a href="">
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
   </a>
  </span>
  <span class="option-wrapper">
   <a href="">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
   </a>
  </span>
  <span class="option-wrapper">
   <a href="">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
   </a>
  </span>
  <span class="option-wrapper">
   <a href="">
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
   </a>
  </span>
 </body>
 <html>
```